# Does Hibernate re-attach Entities automatically in new Transactions?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

A Token entity is loaded via TokenService which fetches the Token through a JpaRepository. My understanding is that for this read operation a transactional block is automatically provided.

After that I call `PasswordService#resetPassword` which is annotated with Spring's `@Transactional`. The previously fetched Token is passed via parameter. Then it's validationTime-property gets altered.

```java
@Controller
public class UserAccountController {

    @PostMapping("/reset")
    public String processPasswordReset(PasswordResetDto resetDto) {

        String tokenSequence = resetDto.getTokenSequence();
        Token token = tokenService.findBySequence(tokenSequence);

        passwordService.resetPassword(token);

        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
public class PasswordService {

    @Transactional
    public void resetPassword(Token token) {

        token.setValidationTime(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }
}
```

Surprisingly the Token will be updated when leaving the trasactional block without having explicitly saved the Token. This leads me to the assumption that a dirty check is done and Hibernate updates the token automatically.

What I don't fully understand is, how does Hibernate achieve to manage this token although I don't explicitly fetch it again within the transaction? As far as I know, when I fetch the token again, I would get a 1st level cached version. But this way Hibernate must somehow figure out itself that I want to update the entity.

Does Hibernate automatically re-attach entities when cached entities gets passed into a transactional block? Or is there something else going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate will not re-attach the entities automatically in the new transaction. It is most probably because you are using the default spring-boot setting which will enable "[Open EntityManager in View](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/data.html#data.sql.jpa-and-spring-data.open-entity-manager-in-view)" pattern.
This pattern basically will open a transaction at the beginning when processing an HTTP request and complete the transaction when sending out the HTTP response.

It means that when `passwordService#resetPassword()` is executed , the transaction is actually still active and hence the `Token` passed to it is still managed by Hibernate. So dirty checking is still applied on it. Then when committing the transaction , hibernate knows it is dirty and hence generate the related SQL to update it.

> Surprisingly the Token will be updated when leaving the trasactional
> block without having explicitly saved the Token.

This is one of the misconception of using hibernate. You do not need explicitly call any methods on the `EntityManager` to update. As long as an entity is still managed and is dirty , it will be updated when the transactional commit which I quote such behaviour from the documentation as below.

From [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-managed-state) :

> Entities in managed/persistent state may be manipulated by the
> application, and any changes will be automatically detected and
> persisted when the persistence context is flushed. There is no need to
> call a particular method to make your modifications persistent.

And from [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#flushing-auto) , it will auto flush the persistence context by default just prior to committing the transaction :

> By default, Hibernate uses the AUTO flush mode which triggers a flush
> in the following circumstances:
>
> - prior to committing a Transaction
> - prior to executing a JPQL/HQL query that overlaps with the queued
>   entity actions
> - before executing any native SQL query that has no registered
>   synchronization

Comment: Many thanks for this clear and understandable explanation. Yes, it is the `Open EntityManager in View` pattern which causes this behavior. I didn't have this on my radar, although I surely must have overflown it when reading Spring docs. But to be honest: two lines mentioning something about lazy loading is not the big burner ;). Anyhow, you helped a lot and from now on I will never forget this feature again.